# Remove fragment during Activity's onStop()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In one of my apps I'm trying to implement the following logic:

1) During Activity's onStart() start some network operation and add progress fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    refreshData();
}

private void refreshData() {
    if (!isInProgress)
    {
       showSpinner();
    }
    //Do boring network request
    .......
}

private void showSpinner() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(new ProgressFragment(), "").addToBackStack("")
        .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

private void hideSpinner() {
   getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

2) During onStop() - cancel active network operation (if any) and stop progress bar (if running):

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (isInProgress) {
        //cancel network op
        ....
        hideSpinner();
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

3) Save some UI state during onSaveInstanceState():

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

So, the problem is that `onSaveInstanceState()` is called before `onStop()`, so when I try to remove my progress bar - I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` exception

Apparently I am missing something fundamental in Activity<->Fragment interaction, so what's the right way to handle my use case?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this one. But I think `onSaveInstanceState()` is linked with the `onStop()` method. So maybe you could put the code that's currently in your `onStop()` into `onPause()` instead?

Comment: @Dreagen `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called prior to `onStop()` (if it is called at all -- state isn't saved if the Activity is finishing). However, prior to Android 3.0 it may be called prior to `onPause()`.

Comment: Although it doesn't offer a solution for your particular case, [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) is a great resource about the problem of doing fragment transactions in response to asynchronous processes that aren't directly attached to the activity lifecycle.

Comment: @kcoppock thanks for the link! Reading it now :) Super useful!

Comment: I might be missing something, but if your activity is closing then why do you need to do hideSpinner();? It will disappear anyway. If activity is just dissapearing (no onDestroy() called), then once you will go back to your activity - then you should be able to remove fragments without IllegalStateException firing.

Comment: @marcin_j It could also be going to the background. I agree that just starting/stopping the network request in `onStart()`/`onStop()` is questionable (`onStop()`/`onStart()` will happen on rotation as well -- you probably want to retain the network request), but the problem of committing transactions not in response to user interactions is definitely a real issue.

Comment: True. After reading article, I would take suggestion to avoid committing transactions during async callbacks as a base rule and will rework my design a bit. Anyways most likely I will run into even bigger issues later if I implement some workaround for this problem here. Link to article did really help, so if you post it as an answer, I tend to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation overall is to avoid committing transactions in response to asynchronous events. See [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) for more information. However, sometimes it's unavoidable, and you can set up some more complex state checking and recovery.

For your particular case (where it seems you want to network request to stop as soon as the Activity is no longer visible), you could do something to this effect:

```
public class SampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String PROGRESS_FRAGMENT = "progress_fragment";

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        refreshData();
    }

    private void refreshData() {
        if (!isInProgress) {
            isInProgress = true;
            showSpinner();
        }
    }

    private void cancelRefresh() {
        if (isInProgress) {
            isInProgress = false;
            //cancel request
            hideSpinner();
        }
    }

    private void showSpinner() {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(new ProgressFragment(), PROGRESS_FRAGMENT)
                .commit();
    }

    private void hideSpinner() {
        FragmentManager mgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment spinner = mgr.findFragmentByTag(PROGRESS_FRAGMENT);
        if (spinner != null) {
            mgr.beginTransaction()
               .remove(spinner)
               .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        cancelRefresh();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        cancelRefresh();
    }
}
```

Since you don't know that `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called, you can call cancel on both `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onStop()`. With the flag set, and the tag to track the fragment, it will only execute once, and should be safe.

Comment: Thanks! Please add also a link to the article you posted in comments which inspired me to rework my design :). Can definitely be useful to others

Comment: Done :) Glad it helped you out. I've had a lot of experience with this -- I ended up making a headless fragment that's added to the activity and retains its state, then sends messages back for events via a handler. When the activity state is saved, I put the fragment into a detached state (where it queues up message delivery), and then when the activity is resumed I clear the flag and the messages are then delivered in order.

Answer (score 2):

explanation for the causes of this Exception:

I looked into KitKat sources, and it appears `popBackStack` executes its workings using handler (enqueues its action):

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#499

so it will execute after whole lifecycle of current event.

You could try with  popBackStackImmediate, but it also executes checkStateLoss(); at the very begining

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#508

and checkStateLoss() checks variable mStateSaved which is set to true in onSaveInstanceState (but couldnt find this source part).

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#1321

Comment: Vote-up for checking out sources, but unfortunately the real problem is that activity image is already saved at the moment `onStop` is called. `mStateSaved` is set to `true` inside `saveAllState()` method call called by Activity during onSaveInstanceState(). See [activity sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java). So it doesn't really make any difference if I call `popBackStackImmediate()` or wait until lifecycle chain is completed